# Throwing a warning message to install few uninstalled plugins on Eclipse launch after I updated with Groovy library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I came across a Maven project which has Groovy files in it. Those Groovy files were not getting recognized during initial compilation. So, I added groovy libraries in build path.

Due to that, when autobuild is triggered it shows the following error window:

[image]

Also, I am not able to decompile the dependent jars and all the projects went into error state.

I tried restarting my eclipse and it asked me to install the following plugins:
[image]

When I click on install, it prompts me the following error window:

[image]

I am not sure if reverting back all my changes of adding Groovy libraries is a good idea! Any leads on handling this situation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you added the Groovy Development Tools to eclipse.  GDT patches the Java Development Tools (and provides LanguageSupportFactory class mentioned above).  If you use the incorrect version of GDT to patch JDT, eclipse can end up in a very bad state.

I recommend looking at Help > About Eclipse Platform > Installation Details > Installation History.  You can revert to a previous state where GDT was not installed.  If you want to add back GDT, be sure you use the update site that matches the version of eclipse you are using.